# On the Lebesgue measure of the set of small values of an analytic function on C

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ is not identically zero. For each $\varepsilon>0$, I denotes ${U_\varepsilon } = \left\{ {z \in \mathbb{C}:\left| {f\left( z \right)} \right| <\varepsilon } \right\}$. My question is: Is there $m(U_{\varepsilon})\to 0$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$ ? Here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: When you say $f \neq 0$ do you mean that $f$ has no zeros or that it is not identically zero?

Comment: No, consider $1 / z$. Then $m(U_{\epsilon})$ is constantly infinity.

Comment: The function $f$ is not identically zero.

Comment: @user54092: $1/z$ is not analytic.

Comment: I wonder if there is any nonpolynomial example where this is true.

Comment: "$f \ne 0$": You can't save your conjecture so easily! Take $f(z)=e^z$ instead of mrf's $\sin z$, and nearly the same reasoning applies: $f$ is periodic, and approaches $0$ arbitrarily closely.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I'm guessing no.

Comment: I understand the examples of mrf and TonyK. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you're saying it is not *identically* zero, then the idea of an entire function with infinitely many zeros will get you started, and $\sin z$ will do the job, since you will have infinitely many disks of the same radius where $|\sin z| < \varepsilon$. This is just the usual phenomenon that we do not have continuity of measure from above on an infinite measure space.

Comment: Thank Ian a lot. But I have a more question to you: What happens if ${U_\varepsilon } = \left\{ {z \in \mathbb{C}:\left| z \right| \leqslant R,\,\,\left| {f\left( z \right)} \right| \leqslant \varepsilon } \right\}$, ($R$ fixed) ?.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, take for example $f(z) = \sin z$. Then $f$ has an infinite number of zeros, and is $2\pi$-periodic so $U_\varepsilon$ contains a countable number of disjoint congruent open sets each having (the same) positive measure, and thus $m(U_\varepsilon) = \infty$ for all $\varepsilon$.